# Registeration of Event using Callback in C

Tags: c, callback, event-handling

I want to register event using callback i.e. function pointer in C

```
typedef void (*event_cb_t)(const struct event *evt, void *userdata);

enum evt{
EVENT_WRITE=0
,EVENT_READ,
EVENT_CLOSE
};

struct event_cb {
event_cb_t cb;
void *data;
};

static void my_event_cb(int event, void *data)
{
if(event ==EVENT_CLOSE)
 //some code 
 if (event == EVENT_READ)
 // some code
 }


 int event_cb_register(event_cb_t cb, void *userdata){

   printf("hi");
   return 0;

  }

  int main()
  {
  struct event_cb *callback;

  callback->data=NULL;
  event_cb_register(my_event_cb, NULL);
  return 0;
  }
```

I want to know when argument 1 of `event_cb_register` will be called?

Means as soon as `event_cb_register` is called or after when `event_cb_register` finished its functioning?

Answer (score 0):

As your code stands, `my_event_cb` is never called. The address of it is passed to `event_cb_register` but that does nothing with the pointer.

`my_every_cb` should be copying the pointer into a variable which is of type `struct event_cb`. Later code can use that variable to call `my_event_cb` when appropriate.